# compareAndSet vs incrementAndGet 

Tags: java, concurrency

Doing a course on concurrent programming.

As an example we have

```
final class Counter {

        private AtomicInteger value;

        public long getValue() {
            return value.get();
        }

        public long increment() {
            int v;
            do {
                v = value.get();
            }
            while(!value.compareAndSet(v, v+1));
            return v+1;
        }
}
```

Why would you use compareAndSet in this case and not incrementAndGet ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the the implementation of `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` method from the JDK version I have on my machine:

```
/**
 * Atomically increments by one the current value.
 *
 * @return the updated value
 */
public final int incrementAndGet() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the implementation is very similar to yours.

PS: Why do you compute `v+1` twice?

Comment: thanks that's just what I was looking for.  Like I mentioned, this example was given by a professor.  I don't know why he computes v+1 twice! ps where on your machine did you find this source code?

Comment: Sun/Oracle ships java sources as part of the JDK. It is usually bundled as an `src.jar` or `src.zip` file. On Windows, this file would be within the JDK installation directory. On Mac it would be at some directory like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home`. Note that the JDK - development kit - is different from JRE - the runtime environment. Sources are included only in JDK.

Answer (score 2):

From the Java docs,

**compareAndSet :**

> Atomically sets the value to the given
>   updated value if the current value ==
>   the expected value.

```
public final boolean compareAndSet(V expect,
                                   V update)
```

**incrementAndGet :**

> Atomically increments by one the
>   current value.

```
public final int incrementAndGet()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since compareAndSet basically does the same, I can't think about a single reason to use this handwritten implementation of increment.

Comment: Did you mean "incrementAndGet basically does the same"?

Comment: I can think of a reason, the teacher wanted you teach `compareAndSet` and he couldn't think of a better example...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the Class Counter implements the value increment in it's own way, and JDK `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` also implements it in it's own way. But they also use  the CAS method `compareAndSet(V expect ,V newValue)`.
So these two kinds of implementation have no difference. The minor difference between the two ways is  the circulation form. BTW, answer for compute v+1 twice.

```
while(!value.compareAndSet(v, v+1));----v+1 is the parameter for function , and realize value to add 1;
        return v+1;  v+1 is the return value;
```